# Visual Studio Upgrade advice required

Tags: visual-studio-2015

how to upgrade Visual studio community 2015 version to visual studio Enterprise 2015? Is there a way I can do this without uninstalling Visual Studio Community 2015?

Comment: I'm not 100% with community but usually the new installer will detect the previous version and 'upgrade' it.